# Cant see within GoogleMap view

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am able to see my location marker, but rest of the map view is blank. Check the below image: 
[image]

I am using google maps SDK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From google developer console I regenerated the key, this time I restricted it for iOS only, thus it asked for my bundle id, returning me with the API key that I replaced in my code at 'GMSServices' and also in 'GoogleService-Info.plist'

Comment: When you answering or adding more details your own question better to add its as comment

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: then why do i have an option for answering my own question

Comment: Of course you can answer your own question. The issue with this is that it doesn't read like an answer. Did this actually solve your issue? If so, maybe you can make that clear in your answer. Also, consider accepting your own answer.

Comment: so should I make it more readable, i can like add screenshots for the steps as these steps resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

*If you don't have the app bundle id added to your google APIs console. The bundle id (eg., domain.appname.company) is what google uses to verify that an app is allowed to use a certain api key. If you've moved your app from one developer account to another, you've probably changed the bundle id in the process. Fortunately, google allows you to associate multiple bundle ids with a single api key.*

To add a new bundle id:

- Verify the bundle id you are using in xcode (select the target and
  look under summary)
- Login to https://code.google.com/apis/console/
- Select "API Access" on the left column
- Select "Edit allowed iOS apps" under the "key for iOS apps" section
- Add the bundle id used in the enterprise build

Comment: I am unable to find  "API Access", I think the google has updated there UI.